# Can a player who has an Xbox one play online with a player with Xbox One S?

Tags: xbox-one

Is Xbox One compatible with Xbox One S when playing online

Answer (score 3):

Yes they can of course it is the same console. Even they can play with Xbox 360 players but only in backward compatible games. But in Xbox One games, yes they can play together.

Comment: Basically, the Xbox One S is and Xbox One with a face lift.  Just like how the Xbox 360 Slim and Xbox 360 was.